# SQL Query to show instock always but do 2 lots of ordering

Tags: sql, sorting, select

Not sure how this would work but I can give a brief description.

I have database I want to sort but kind of sort twice in same statement.

I have products, some in stock and some out of stock, I want to always show in stock before any out of stock regardless of sorting order.
So it will sort A-Z of all in stock items first and the same query has to then show A-Z of out of stock.
Sorting in price order would show Low-High of in stock and then do the same for out of stock again in same query.

Basically, I want to be sure they can always see all the in stock items first at all times.

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple terms in the `order by` clause:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     products
ORDER BY in_stock DESC, name ASC
```